# How to allocate more physical memory to Mathematica?

Tags: memory, kernel

My MacBook Pro (2019) has 32 GB of memory, but when I work with a large array reaching 1 GB of storage, the Mathematica Kernel only gets a little more of 1 GB, but gets allocated a lot of virtual storage. This slows down any, even very simple computation on the array. I have no big other processes running and Apple's "Activity Monitor" shows only a very small "Memory Pressure". Is it possible to allocate more physical memory to the Kernel?